# ApiController route override not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, owin, self-hosting

I have the problem, that in my Asp.Net OWIN self hosted web service route overriding with the `Route`-attribute does not work.

My initial routing looks like this:

```
string routeTempl = "api/" + EndpointManager.API_VERSION + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}";

// Configure Web API for self-host. 
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: routeTempl,
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class GeneralController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ping the api, mostly for testing reason
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Current server datetime</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public DateTime Ping()
    {
        // return datetime as ping
        return DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current api version
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Api-Version as a string</returns>
    [HttpGet, Route("~/api/version")]
    public string ApiVersion()
    {
        return EndpointManager.API_VERSION;
    }
}
```

The ping-method is accessable as i want it, over: `http://localhost:48000/api/v1-0/general/ping`

But i can not access the ApiVersion-Method over: `http://localhost:48000/api/version`

Does any one has an idea, what i am doing wrong in the `Route`-attribute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add that line after your routing configuration:

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();